# Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Im faily new to React-native, I am trying to create a tab component and use it on my index.android.js
Here is my index.android.js. The import stuff is on top i did not include it here.

```
import Tabs from './app/Tabs';

export default class ExpenseManagerProject extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Tabs/>
    <Text>
      wew
    </Text>
  </View>

);
}
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ExpenseManagerProject', () => ExpenseManagerProject);
```

And here is my Tabs component

```
export default class Tabs extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <TabBarIOS
    unselectedTintColor="yellow"
    tintColor="white"
    unselectedItemTintColor="red"
    barTintColor="darkslateblue">
      <TabBarIOS.Item title="One">Wew
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
      <TabBarIOS.Item title="Two">Two
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
      <TabBarIOS.Item title="One">Three
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
  </TabBarIOS>
);
}
}
module.exports = Tabs;
```

i get the error **Element type is invalid: expected a string.......but got undefined. Check render method of "Tabs"**

I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TabBarIOS is not going to work under Android**. It's only for iOS.

This might suit your purpose for Android:
https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

Btw, just looking at your code, you do not have to `module.exports = Tabs;` since you already `export default` the component.

Comment: owh I see, i did not know that.
Thank you very much for this sir